# NotificationManager.notify is not working as expected

Tags: android, notifications

The app I am making has the file transfer ability, and I show its progress inside of a notification with an option to stop the transfer.
The problem is that every time `NotificationManager.notify` is called (and it has to be called every time the progress changes), the system notification sound is played (this results in a lot of spam), and the button for stopping the transfer becomes unusable.

Not updating the progress bar allows for the "Stop transfer" button to be pressed.
Another thing I noticed is that the sound spam is present on Android 8.x, but not on 5.x.

Creating the notification:

```
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(cont, "default")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.file)
            .setContentTitle("File transfer app")
            .setContentText((down ? "Downloading " : "Uploading ") + fileName)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setProgress(100, 0, indeterminate);
    Intent notifyButton = new Intent();
    notifyButton.setAction("STOP_TRANSFER");
    notifyButton.putExtra("id", notifId);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont, notifId, notifyButton, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.close, "Stop transfer", pendingIntent);
    all.add(this);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifId, mBuilder.build());
```

Updating its progress:

```
mBuilder.setProgress(this.max, progress, indeterminate);
mNotificationManager.notify(notifId, mBuilder.build());
```

I expected the progress bar to update normally without making a sound every time it moves, and to allow me to cancel the transfer at any time.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: To stop the sound spam, you could try to use the option setOnlyAlertOnce(true) on your builder.

Comment: @urukh that solved the sound spam problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to call mNotificationManager.cancel() if your updating notification continuously to just notify progress.

```
if(update){
   mNotificationManager.cancel(notifId) 
 }
mNotificationManager.notify(notifId, mBuilder.build());
```